# Weird behaviour of ruby regex in rails with utf8 char

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-3, utf-8

I have problem with one of my validation regex when using nonstandard utf-8 character. So, I run a few experiments and it appears that ruby regex behave different when there are with rails environment or in plain ruby.

I post here my expriment with a Chinese string.

In ruby "pure" :

```
string = "運動會"
puts string[/\A[\w]*\z/]
=> match "運動會" - ok
```

In rails :

```
# coding: utf-8
task :test => :environment do
  string = "運動會"
  puts string[/\A[\w]*\z/]
end
$ rake test
=> nothing - not ok
```

If I omit `# coding: utf-8`, it comes with `invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII)`. Anyway, even with this, it doesn't match.

Of course, I have checked everything (ruby_version, encoding of script files in utf-8..)

I use :

- Rails 3.0.7
- Ruby 1.9.2 (ruby-1.9.2-p180)

So my conclusion is that rails alter the way regex behave and I did not find a way to make it behaves like in normal ruby.

Comment: Can't really help with ror, but +1 for a good question - it's obvious you've tried and did your homework.

Comment: Thank you, yeah I keep searching found great articles about utf-8 and ruby 1.8/1.9 but nothing related with this issue.

Comment: FWIW - your test works in 1.8.7 - not sure if that's an option for you.

Comment: I cut and paste your code into both IRB and Rails console and they returned "nil". I believe that is correct, but I'm not sure how Regex handles Chinese characters. Have you tried using the "u" operator on the regex? string[/\A[\w]*\z/u]

Comment: Yeah, I have already try the /u operator, do not change anything.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, I found an answer to my problem. The `\w` behaves only with ascii character in ruby 1.9 against all unicode caracter in ruby 1.8. In ruby 1.9, now we have to use : `[\w\P{ASCII}]`

More infos : http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/210770

Comment: What a nice silent and hard to detect breakage :)